# AWS console application throws error when run on the cloud

Tags: c#, .net, dll, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm having a bit of a problem running an AWS Console Application created in VS2010, on the cloud, on the EC2.

When ran on my desktop, it poses no problems, but, when moved to the cloud, it thrown an error saying that it cannot find the AWSSDK.dll.

I changed the path of the references, so that it would mimic the folder structure on the cloud, but that didn't work.

I tried to put another copy of the dll in the application folder and hoped for a miracle, but that didn't work either.

The last thing I tried was to load the dll manually with the AssemblyResolve, but that didn't work either.

Thanks, Catalin

Comment: Managed to figure it out. A co worker put his version of the aws dll in the application instead of mine(the one I actually built the application with).

Answer (score 0):

you may visit here
http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/
stick with the style of the code sample
i was tried previously and success =D

Comment: the code works. the application just doesn't find that specific dll when it starts. it just freezes and when closed, it shoes an error that it does not find the dll before hitting even the first line of code.